# How to save large chat history of WhatsApp in Android phone

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I'm not able to store my WhatsApp chat of single contact in email chat because of large amount of messages so how is it possible?

Comment: Sync with Google drive or save locally. WhatsApp > Settings > Conversation > Save conversation > Add your address or save locally

Comment: Why is it a problem to save large files in your email? Are you getting some errors when trying? If so, what are they?

Comment: @esQmo_ are you on the latest version of whatsapp? Cuz i remembered there used to be something similar to what you're saying, but apparently WhatsApp stopped that option, and the only option if saving a single chat with one person is only possible by emailing the chat to yourself. I'm Google drive you can only backup all the chats, and u can't view them unless u restore all at once. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Your WhatsApp chats are automatically backed up and saved daily to your phone's memory. You can also periodically backup your WhatsApp chats to Google Drive. 
To backup your chats, go toWhatsApp > Menu Button > Settings > Chats> Chat backup > Back Up.
Now, to export a copy of the history of an **individual** chat or group, use the Email chatfeature instead:

*Open the chat for the individual or group.Tap the Menu Button.Tap More.Tap Email chat.Choose whether to Attach Media or not*

Note: **When sending with media, you can send up to 10,000 latest messages. Without media, you can send 40,000 messages. These constraints are due to maximum email sizes.**

- Soure: [WhatsaApp FAQ](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/23756533/?category=5245251)